# JNA Java Pointer to BOOL

Tags: java, integer, boolean, jna

I'm trying to convert this function to JNA:

```
        DWORD WINAPI WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty(
        __in        HANDLE hClientHandle,
        __in        WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_OPCODE OpCode,
        __in        DWORD dwDataSize,
        __in        PVOID pvData,
        __out_opt   PWLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON pFailReason,
        __reserved  PVOID pvReserved
        );
```

As I have now:

```
     int WlanHostedNetworpSetProperty(HANDLE hClientHandle, IntByReference OpCode,int dwDataSize, Pointer pvData, IntByReference pFailReason, Pointer pvReserved);
```

Which should be right.

However when OpCode is wlan_hosted_network_opcode_enable, aka 3, it wants the pvData to be BOOL. I read that BOOL is an integer, but doing pvData.setInteger(1) will crash the application. Any help would be great.

The crash is an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), when the `OpCode` is `wlan_hosted_network_opcode_enable`:

> A pointer to **BOOL** is passed in the *pvData* parameter.

Note that it's a *pointer* to `BOOL`, not an actual `BOOL` value, that is needed.

As you found, changing to an `IntByReference` solved the problem, likely because an `int` and `BOOL` are the same size on your platform, and because now you're passing a valid pointer.

Comment: However it now returns "Bad parameters" instead of ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED or similar. Is this because the dwDataSize is set wrong (to 4)?

Comment: Nvm, OpCode should not be a pointer, that was what it was complaining about.